# Merge arrays with underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

After performing a few underscore.js operations (`_.map`, `_.each`, `_.pluck`, and `_.flatten`), I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
var userArray = [
  {id: 123456, username: "bill123", group: "ONE"},
  {id: 123457, username: "joe123", group: "TWO"},
  {id: 123457, username: "joe123", group: "TWO"},
  {id: 123458, username: "jim123", group: "ONE"}
]
```

I need to create a new array, with duplicates removed, and a count of how many times the object appeared in the array.  I am able to get the desired results with two separate [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) functions,  but am having trouble merging the two results.

The working functions are as follows:

```
var uniqUsers = _.uniq(taggedUsers, false, function(user) {
  return user.id
});
  //returns array of unique objects in the same format as above
  //[{id: 123457, username: "joe123", group: "TWO"},...]

var userCounts = _.countBy(taggedUsers, "id");
  //returns the count for each user in the userArray in a single object
  //{123456: 1, 123457: 2, 123458: 1}
```

What's the best approach for returning an array of objects like this:

```
{id: 123457, username: "joe123", group: "TWO", count: 2}
```

Can I add additional fields to the `_.countBy` function?  Or do I need to do something with `_.map`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks

Comment: Also would be a plus if the array is sorted by count !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` on `userCounts` to create a new array which you can then sort.

```
var userArray = [
  {id: 123456, username: "bill123", group: "ONE"},
  {id: 123457, username: "joe123", group: "TWO"},
  {id: 123457, username: "joe123", group: "TWO"},
  {id: 123458, username: "jim123", group: "ONE"}
];

var userCounts = _.countBy(userArray, "id");

var result = _.sortBy(_.map(userCounts, function(count, id) {
  var user = _.findWhere(userArray, {id: Number(id)});  
  return _.extend({}, user, {count: count});
}), 'count');

console.log(result);
```

Result:

```
[[object Object] {
  count: 1,
  group: "ONE",
  id: 123456,
  username: "bill123"
}, [object Object] {
  count: 1,
  group: "ONE",
  id: 123458,
  username: "jim123"
}, [object Object] {
  count: 2,
  group: "TWO",
  id: 123457,
  username: "joe123"
}]
```

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/valapijequ/edit?js,console)

Comment: Note that this will mutate the original objects in the `userArray`. If this isn't desirable, change `return _.extend(user, { count: count });` to `return _.extend({}, user, { count: count });`.

Comment: Good point, I'll edit since I did not intend to change the original set.

Comment: Thank you @AnidMonsur, that solution works (sorry for the delayed response).  Looking at the edit, what is the difference between including/excluding the `{}` in the `_.extend` function? @GregL

Comment: And this also sorts by smallest count to largest count, how could I reverse it? In mongo I can use `{$sort { count: -1 }}` and `{$sort { count: -1 }}`, but do not see that param in underscore @AnidMonsur @GregL

Comment: And (last one), does underscore.js support sorting by multiple params? Say i wanted to sort by `group` alphabetically, then `count` largest to smallest

Comment: Passing an empty object as the first parameter to `_.extend` ensures the original user in `userArray` is not modified. Your other questions are already answered on SO elsewhere. Sorting can be chained, and you can use `reverse()` on any array.

Answer (score 3):

I would just do it in two `_.each`s:

```
var uniquedUsersWithCount = [],
    userIDToCount = {};

_.each(taggedUsers, function (user) {
  if (userIDToCount[user.id] !== undefined) {
    userIDToCount[user.id] += 1;
  } else {
    userIDToCount[user.id] = 0;
    uniquedUsersWithCount.push(user);
  }
});

_.each(uniquedUsersWithCount, function (user) {
  var count = userIDToCount[user.id];
  if (count !== undefined) {
    user.count = count;
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't use the full power of Underscore, but it is probably clearer code that is easier to read.

Comment: Thank you this is cool, if i understand correctly, you are creating an empty array, pushing new users to it with a count of 1, but if the user already exists add 1 to the count field?

Comment: But what is the second `_each` function doing? A little confused by that @Vinay

Comment: The first loop is constructing a mapping of `userID` (Number) -> `count` (Number) as well as pushing the unique users (based on ID) to the `uniqueUsersWithCount` array. The second loop is adding a `count` field based on the previously constructed map to each entry in the `uniqueUsersWithCount` array.